# $ \left \langle a \right \rangle $ is a subgroup of centraliser of $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Question:

For any element $a$ in a group $G$, prove that $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ is a subgroup of $c\left ( a \right )$.

I have shown that the centraliser of a is a group; in particular, a subgroup.
Also, $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ is a subset of the centraliser of a.

> By a certain theorem:
>
> $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ is a subgroup of a group G.

This should be simple but I am unable to finish this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $c(a)$ and $\langle a \rangle$ are subgroups of $G$, so all you need to show is that $\langle a \rangle$ is contained in $c(a)$ (if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ is a subset of $K$ then $H$ is automatically a subgroup of $K$).  To show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a subset of $c(a)$, you need to check that every element of $\langle a \rangle$ commutes with $a$.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roadmap:

- If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $a \in H$, then $ \langle a \rangle \subseteq H$.
- $C(a)$ is a subgroup of $G$.
- $a \in C(a)$.

The first fact follows at once from the definition/characterization of $ \langle a \rangle$ as the smallest subgroup that contains $a$. Or you can do it directly: if $a \in H$ then $a^n \in H$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Looks good. I couldn't figure out the consequence 'then' from the first line.

Answer (score 1):

it is simple to verify that the centralizer of a subgroup H of G
is a subgroup of G, but be careful that H may not be a subgroup of
the centralizer, more precisely H is a subgroup of the centralizer
iff H is abelian (just write the definition of the centralizer of
a subgroup). in your case H is the cyclic sub-group generated by a,
thus was the result.